# Jackson - how to set deserialization naming strategy without specifying @JsonProperty in WebClient

Tags: java, json-deserialization, jackson-databind, spring-webclient

As I know, specifying property naming strategy only affects serialization, not deserialization. When deserializing, even when I know the incoming JSON is camel cased, I cannot get the below config to work, and had to use `@JsonProperties` on each field:

```java
    private final MemberApiProperties memberApiProperties;
    private final WebClient webClient;
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public MemberApiClient(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder,
                           CustomWebClientBuilder webClientBuilder,
                           MemberApiProperties properties) {
        this.memberApiProperties = properties;
        this.objectMapper = objectMapperBuilder
                .propertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.LOWER_CAMEL_CASE)
                .build();
        this.webClient = webClientBuilder
                .build(properties, configurer -> {
                    configurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonEncoder(new Jackson2JsonEncoder(objectMapper));
                    configurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(objectMapper));
                });
    }
```

"I cannot get it to work" means: with this setting, in the incoming dto, when it is "id" or "name", values are set; when it is "propertyName", the field is always null. Only when I set the `@JsonProperty("propertyName")`, `propertyName` began to be non-null.

So, is there some way to specify a naming strategy for deserialization without using `@JsonProperty`?